# TP-LINK TL-WN727N Wireless N150 adapter is not working on Windows Server 2012

Tags: usb, drivers

I have searched for drivers from [this site](http://www.tp-link.in/products/details/TL-WN727N.html), but have been unable to find an appropriate driver for the OS I was searching for. I have also installed drivers from that site and tried the driver disk provided with the device. However nothing worked for me.

The hardware is not being detected by OS. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Don’t panic! Wi-Fi/Wireless Adapaters are disabled by default in Windows Server 2012. You don’t need to update, uninstall or reinstall your Wireless Adapter.

Just follow the following steps to enable wireless connections:

Go to Server Manager.
Click Manage in the upper right corner.
Click Add Roles and Features.
Click Next > Next > Next.
At Server Selection select your server.
Click Next > Next.
At Features check Wireless LAN Services.
Click Next > Install.
Restart your server.
Connect to your wireless network.